# pyrogram - Filter commands addressed to the bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, pyrogram

If I filter a command using something like `filters.command(["my_command"]`, in groups the bot gets notified when I execute the command `/my_command`, but if I address it to the bot (e.g. `/my_command@MyBot`) it won't get notified.

How can I modify the filter to get notified in both cases (independently on the bot name)?

Thanks

Comment: `filters.command(["my_command", "my_command@myBot"]`

Comment: ok, but I prefer not to write the bot name in the code (I have lots of bots with the same code), is there a way to filter it without hard-coding the name?

Comment: You could write a loop that will duplicate each command with the name of the bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex

```
with app:
    bot_username = app.get_me().username

@app.on_message( filters.regex(f'^/my_command($|@{bot_username}$)') )
def handler( client, message ):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass each option to `filter.commands`, including the variants with the bot name.

---

If you're looking for a more dynamic solution, you can use something like

```py
commands = [ 'hello', 'world' ]
myBot = 'myBotName'

for i in range(len(commands)):
    commands.append(commands[i] + "@" + myBot)

print(commands)
// ['hello', 'world', 'hello@myBotName', 'world@myBotName']
```

That will loop over a list of commands, and the same command with the bot name attached.

For even more copy/paste logic, you can retrieve the bot name from `pyrogram` itself.

---

If we take a look at Pyrogram's `User` class; we'll see the following data:

> - username (str, optional) – User’s or **bot’s** username.

<sup>[[Link to documentation]](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/User)</sup>

This seems like a perfect fit to automate the `myBot` variable in my example above.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the best solution would be to get the bot name from pyrogram and create the string dynamically

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with pyrogram, so I can't tell you how exactly. It is available though the telegram Api so there must be a option for it in pyrogram.

Comment: Please see my edit @yuko, I guess the `user.username` should be wat you're looking for.